# react-switch doesn't call onChange when toggled to the initial state

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import Switch from "react-switch";

const SignInSecurity = (props) => {
  let switchChecked: boolean = false;

  const handleChange = (state: boolean) => {
    console.log("handleChange", state);
    switchChecked = state;
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="isFlex"
      style={props.disabled ? { pointerEvents: "none", opacity: "0.4" } : {}}
    >
      <div className="modal">
        <Switch
          onChange={handleChange}
          checked={props.signInInfoData.twoStepVerification}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignInSecurity;
```

I have an inital value set to the Switch with 'checked' prop.Say it is true on initial load. Now, when I toggle to uncheked, the onChange method is triggered. But, when I toggle back again to checked, the onChange method is not triggered, thus making it unable to detect the latest change and getting wrong output.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use state in this component? That is not really the react way. Also, in the ```handleChange``` method, what does the console log say?

Comment: using it at the reducer level.just short-cut the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I made some changes and it's working fine.

---

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Switch from "react-switch";

const SignInSecurity = props => {
  const [switchChecked, setStateChecked] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = state => {
    console.log("handleChange", state);
    setStateChecked(state);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="isFlex"
      style={props.disabled ? { pointerEvents: "none", opacity: "0.4" } : {}}
    >
      <div className="modal">
        <Switch onChange={handleChange} checked={switchChecked} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignInSecurity;
```

Also attaching a working example , hope this will help you out!

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-switch-working-vzcte

Comment: Thank u sir,   actually found a clue from ur answer.  react-switch onChange was getting called only when the state corresponding to the checked prop changes.I've modified my reducer logic accordingly & its working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  const handleChange = (state: boolean) => {
    console.log("handleChange", state);
    switchChecked = !state;
  };
```